# Why GetStandardStream in mshta fails directly but works in a for?

Tags: javascript, cmd, hta

Try this:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %a in (`mshta "javascript:new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).Write('Hello World');close()"`) do @echo //%a//
```

Or this:

```
mshta "javascript:new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).Write('Hello World');close()" | for /f "delims=" %a in ('findstr "^"') do @echo //%a//
```

You get

```
//Hello World//
```

But if you try the backquoted command directly you get an error.

```
mshta "javascript:new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).Write('Hello World');close()"
```

Shouldn't the latter command output the same string but in standard output? Why do I need the `for /f`? Doesn't the `for` just get the output of the backquoted command and assign it to `%a`?